# How can I separate the contents of a single textbox in a c# destop application into two interger variables?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a simple desktop application where you can do operations with fractions. I created the Rational class but i need a denominator and  numerator. I can only use 2 textboxes, one for each fraction. Is there a way to separate the contents with a "/" into two different variables?

I wrote some simple code to check the textbox for the "/" but I'm not sure how to separate that into two variables.

```
char denominator;

for(int i = 0; i <= textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
{
    if (textBox1.Text[i] =='/')
    {
        int fromhere = i;

        for(int y = 0; y <= i; i++)
        {
            denominator = textBox1.Text[y];
        }
    }   
}
```

I want to later put those variables in the parameters for my rational object and then be able to allow the user to do operations.

Comment: [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who took time off their day to help me

Answer (score 2):

Easiest and simplest way is to use `string.Spilt()` like this:

```
string[] fraction = textBox1.Text.Split('/');
int numerator = Convert.Into32(fraction[0]);
int denominator = Convert.Into32(fraction[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have one textbox:

```
string input = textBox1.Text;
var twoParts = input.Split('/');

if (twoParts.Length != 2)
{
    // Invalid input
    // TODO 
}

if (!decimal.TryParse(twoParts[0], out var numerator) || !decimal.TryParse(twoParts[1], out var denominator))
{
    // Invalid input
    // TODO
}

var result = numerator / denominator;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the split command which will solve that

```
string line = "123/0215";
string[] splitedData  = line.Split('/');

console.WriteLine(splitedData[0]);
console.WriteLine(splitedData[1]);
```

Output will be :

```
 -> 123
 -> 0215
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a button event:

```
private void SplitAndCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyNo= textBox1.Text ;
        string[] SplitedMyNo = MyNo .Split('/');
        int N1 = int.Parse(SplitedMyNo[0]);
        int N2 = int.Parse(SplitedMyNo[1]);
        int Res = N1 + N2;
        MessageBox.Show( Res.ToString() ) ;
             }
```

[image]